# How to get a list of all network interfaces using ifquery

Tags: ubuntu, debian, linux-networking

The documentation states that

```
ifquery --list
```

gives a list of all interfaces specified in `/etc/network/interfaces` (and includes). In fact in both Debian Jessie and Ubuntu 14.04 it lists all interfaces that have `auto INTERFACENAME` stanza and skips those without `auto` line.

Is there a way to list all interfaces that have `iface NAME` stanza using ifquery?

No, using `ip link list` doesn't do the trick because the interface specified in `/etc/network/interfaces` does not have to exist when `ifquery` is called.

Comment: In the man page for my version ( 0.7.48.1ubuntu10) it states that 
       ifquery -l
              Print names of all interfaces specified with the auto keyword.

Comment: But is there a way to list them all, even those without `auto`

Comment: That is why it is a comment and not an answer :) I am looking at ethtool now.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in another answer `ifconfig -a` will take you there. However, `ifconfig` resides in `/sbin` directory, which is not included in `PATH` for regular users on most platforms and it may be too verbose for your purpose.

The alternative is

```
ip link
```

which is available to regular users.

Comment: Nope. `ip link` is just an alias to `ip link list`. As I specified in my question above, this is not the thing I want.

Comment: `ip link` returns list of active interfaces when `ifquery` returns list from `/etc/network/interfaces`. You can easily do something like `if link | grep eth[0-9] | awk ...` to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Though some think it is a bit dated (what's wrong with tried and true?), I like to use the following to quickly see all network interfaces:

```
ifconfig -a
```

It's part of the net-tools package, exists on pretty much all linux distros since a couple of decades and normally is installed by default.

Comment: Nope. See my comment to `ip link` answer above. I specified in the question that `ip link` (and ifconfig too) don't give the correct answer